# App update data from web periodically

Tags: ios, multitasking

I'm building an iPhone app where most of the content is dynamically loaded from my web server. The content is updated once per day. Here's the issue I ran into when testing my app on my device. I noticed that I would just close the app, and the next day I didn't see the new content. I had to go close the app fully (via multitasking) and then go back into it to update the content.

I could use this in the app delegate:
    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

but, I load all the content in each View Controller... how should I go about re-loading my data?

Also...
If I update the array of objects that the data is pulled from in the UITableView, will the UITableView update automatically?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the documentation for that method also says, "The application also posts a `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification shortly before calling this method to give interested objects a chance to respond to the transition."

Your view controller could be considered an interested object.

Table views can be told to `reloadData`.